# Navigate 3D PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, 3d, itext

I am having 3d PDF File. It contains lots of 3d drawings, but its embedded in a page. We are navigating to drawing in Navigation pane (Model Tree -> views ).

I want to navigate this 3d pdf using C# with iTextSharp.

Please let me know how to achieve it?

For example :

http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part4/chapter16/pdf3d.pdf

The above pdf has model tree. it has model,options and information panel. Now i want to control model selection .

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "navigate this 3d pdf using C# with iTextSharp". I might be misunderstanding you so I apologize, but iTextSharp cannot control a PDF renderer, it can only manipulate the internal file structure of a PDF.

Comment: Hi Chirs Haas , Thanks for your response. I mean , if you open  the sample PDF (http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part4/chapter16/pdf3d.pdf)  . You will find a tool bar with "Views" drop down and Model tree bar. I want to control the "views" drop down from my application .  i will pass the view value  to PDF file. So , i want to control the tool bar and model tree pane control in the pdf.

Comment: For Example : We can control the tool bar in report viewer control using C# . Same  like , i want to control the 3d pdf tool bar using c#.  I will design the tool bar in my application with necessary control which will control the pdf. It will be very useful for my users. iTextSharp is generating the pdf from the drawings . So , i will parse the generated PDF using iTextsharp and same i will control the "views drop down" in the tool bar.

Comment: As per your message, you told that iTextSharp is manipulating the internal file structure of a PDF. So, can we read the "views" drop down values and same same can we select the item in that drop down using iTextSharp ?

Comment: I'm sorry if my questions are frustrating but I'm just just hung up on the word "control". Just to be 100%, you are _not_ talking about looking at a PDF in a PDF viewer and having iTextSharp "control the views" _while_ you are looking at it, right? Instead, you are asking if you can programmatically create views and possibly set a default view so that when you open the PDF in a view you can then click on those, right? There's no native iTextSharp support (AFAIK) for 3D but you can use the raw PDF commands (http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=299) along with section 9.5.3 in the PDF spec.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, coding the functionality inside the PDF should be done with javascript using Adobe Acrobat API.
You should be aware that each version of Adobe Acrobat has many differences.
The standard reference: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf
More focused on 3d reference:
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_3d_api_reference.pdf